# EntityFramework problem with IsDiscriminator in single table inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have 2 simple classes:

```
public abstract class Device
{
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }

    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [Column(IsDiscriminator = true)]
    public int DeviceTypeID { get; set; }
}

public class SomeDevice : Device
{
    public string SomeAdditionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

All is stored in one table:

DeviceID | SerialNumber | DeviceTypeID | SomeAdditionalInfo

But in application I have next exception while retrieving data:

```
Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
```

If I change column DeviceTypeID to Discriminator than everything works fine. Why attribute IsDiscriminator = true is ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Column` attribute from wrong namespace - it is attribute for Linq-to-Sql. Discriminator in entity framework is never mapped as property - EF will create that column automatically. So unless you are using existing database you should simply use:

```
public abstract class Device
{
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In case of existing database you must use fluent API. In your derived context add this to `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
            .Map<SomeDevice>(m => m.Requires("DeviceTypeID")
                                   .HasValue(10));
```